# Erro ao instalar um war no jboss eap 6.2 com myfaces jsf 1.1

Tags: jsf, jboss

Ocorre o erro abaixo ao instalar a aplicação no jboss. Sei que é devido o jboss ter uma implementação do javaserver faces.

```
11:15:04,601 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 182) JBWEB001093: The listener org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener is already configured for this context, the duplicate definition has been ignored
11:15:04,625 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapp]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 182) JBWEB000285: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener from [Module "deployment.MyApp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:74) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3294) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Bem vindo a SO-pt, sugiro que leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Acredito que você deve explicar melhor o que você está tentando fazer, onde está dando o erro e como a comunidade pode ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui instalar a aplicação no jboss mas tive que fazer o seguinte:

Adicionar o arquivo
\WEB_INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <exclusions>
        <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
        <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl"/>
      </exclusions>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Incluir o parâmetro de contexto no web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
      <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
...
```

Este link ajudou bastante 
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/JSF_Guide/en-US/html/jsf.deployer.config.html

Answer (score 0):

A versões modernas dos servidores de aplicação já contam com um ótimo isolamento de classpath por projeto, portanto é muito improvável que o problema seja relacionado a conflitos entre as bibliotecas carregadas pelo seu projeto e as que já existem no servidor.

O problema provavelmente está relacionado a esse exceção:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

conforme respondido nessa pergunta do stackoverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777844/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-faces-config-configurelistener-when-us

Essa classe faz parte do Mojarra, que é um implementação concorrente ao MyFaces.

Ela não deveria ser necessário quando se está usando o MyFaces. A exceção pode estar acontecendo pelos seguintes motivos:

-Existe um `<listener>` definido manualmente no web.xml da aplicação ou no web-fragmet.xml de algum jar dentro da aplicação, que está fazendo referencia a essa classe do Mojarra.

-Existe em algum lugar no classpath um arquivo .tld do Mojarra, que pode estar sendo carregado e conter um `<listener>` apontando também para a classe do Mojarra.

Essa exceção pode ser corrigida, simplemsmente removendo esses listeners.